# Does piecewise continuous imply Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, borel-sets, measurable-functions, piecewise-continuity

It's extremely well-known that continuous functions are Borel measurable, but what about piecewise continuous functions? For the Lebesgue measure, I suspect that we'd have a proof as simple as "continuous functions are measurable, piecewise continuous functions are just continuous functions with a few bits missing, singletons have measure 0, throw in some additivity argument, done", but I'm unsure about the more general case.

Comment: To reinforce Kavi's statement let me say again that measurability of functions is not related to the particular measure but only to the underlying sigma algebra. You can see that directly in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you write down the inverse image of a Borel set you get a finite union of Borel sets. The question in the title has nothing to do with any measure.